# Printing the compared result under last column header

Tags: awk, ksh, gawk

I'm doing a comparision of 2 files file1,file2 using first column in file1 to first column in file2 and retriving corresponding value from 7 th column .

```
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$7;next} {print (($1 in a) ? $0","a[$1] : $0",NA");}' file2.txt file1.txt > tmp && mv tmp file1.txt
```

also on next day it will compare and append the result .

```
cat file1.txt 

N1,N2,N3,N4,N5,N6,D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D6,D7,D8,D9,D10
XX,ZZ,XC,EE,RR,BB,OK,OK,OK,OK,OK,OK,OK,OK
XC,CF,FG,RG,GH,GH,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA
DM,DF,GR,TH,EW,BB

cat file2.txt 

cat file2.txt
DF,GH,MH,FR,FG,GH,NA
XX,ZZ,XC,EE,RR,BB,OK

awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$7;next} {print (($1 in a) ? $0","a[$1] : $0",NA");}' file2.txt file1.txt > tmp && mv tmp file1.txt
```

mv: overwrite `file1.txt'? y

```
 cat file1.txt
N1,N2,N3,N4,N5,N6,D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D6,D7,D8,D9,D10,NA ---> Header
XX,ZZ,XC,EE,RR,BB,OK,OK,OK,OK,OK,OK,OK,OK,OK,OK
XC,CF,FG,RG,GH,GH,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA
DM,DF,GR,TH,EW,BB,NA
```

after adding new row

```
DM,DF,GR,TH,EW
```

problem is it is comparing and printing result for header also and result is printed
 under header D1 instead of D10 for newly inserted row in file1

How can we print like this, compare should exclude header and result under last column header

```
N1,N2,N3,N4,N5,N6,D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D6,D7,D8,D9,D10
XX,ZZ,XC,EE,RR,BB,OK,OK,OK,OK,OK,OK,OK,OK,OK,OK
XC,CF,FG,RG,GH,GH,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA
DM,DF,GR,TH,EW,BB                           ,NA
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid having header updated, change awk's expression to the following:

```
'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$7;next} FNR==1{print $0; next} {print (($1 in a) ? $0","a[$1] : $0",NA");}'
```

In this case 1st line of the `file1.txt` will be printed as is, without any changes.

But don't you also need to have new day (like "D10" in the example) be added to the header on each run? Or you do it elsewhere?

As to the 2nd question (printing new value at the same position in the string for the shorter line as for the longer line), you should further modify awk:

```
'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$7;next} FNR==1{print $0; len=length($0); next} {printf $0; cont=(($1 in a) ? ","a[$1] : ",NA"); for (i=length($0)+1;i<=len-length(cont);i++) printf " " ; print cont;}'
```

Comment: You can remove the `$0` from `print $0`. It will do the default action, print the line.

Comment: @Jotne: Yep, I know, but prefer this way for clarity and readability.

Comment: But how to combine both conditions ?

Comment: Not  printing result in Header and also printing the results of new row under recent header

Comment: N1,N2,N3,N4,N5,N6,D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D6,D7,D8,D9,D10
XX,ZZ,XC,EE,RR,BB,OK,OK,OK,OK,OK,OK,OK,OK,OK,OK
XC,CF,FG,RG,GH,GH,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA
DM,DF,GR,TH,EW,BB ,,,,,,,,,,,NA

Comment: @sam_84: The second awk code line in my answer will do it for you, except that it won't be all the commas (`BB,,,,,NA`) before the last value in the updated row (as in your last comment) - it will rather be many spaces (as needed) followed by 1 comma and new value (`BB               ,NA`) because that's what you asked for in your question.